# jQuery using $.post to upload file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to send POST data by jQuery to my PHP server. And this is what I'm currently receiving (**which is what I want**):

```
client_id: 55
client_name: 'Josh'
age: '35'
extra: array(0) -> array(['preview'] -> true, ['lookup'] -> false)
```

And to achieve this I have the following code:

```
var elements    = [];
var listOfExtra = []

listOfExtra.push({'preview': true, 'lookup': false});

elements['client_id']   = 55;
elements['client_name'] = 'Josh';
elements['age']         = 35;
elements['extra']       = listOfExtra;

$.post(url, $.extend({}, elements));
```

But now I also need to send a file the user has upload, so by doing this:

```
elements['file'] = event.target.files[0];
```

I receive the message `Illegal invocation` in javascript

Since this didn't work I tried to implement a `formData()`:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('client_id', 55);
formData.append('client_name', 'Josh');
formData.append('age', 35);
formData.append('extra', listOfExtra);
formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);

$.ajax(
{
    url: url
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

What happens is that now the `extra` is an `[object][object]`, which is OK, so I just need to stringify it.

```
formData.append('extra', JSON.stringify(listOfExtra));
```

The problem now is that I have lots of code that uses `$_POST['extra'][0]['preview']` (for example) and now I need to decode all of it before and use lots of conditions, like:

```
$extra = isset(json_decode($_POST['extra'])[0]['preview']);

if($extra != null)
   $extraContent = json_decode($_POST['extra'])[0];

$preview = (isset($extraContent) ? $extraContent->preview : $extra[$_POST['extra'][0]['preview']);
```

Is there any way by using `formData()` or `$.post` I can keep the values sent from javascript to PHP like I want and send the file?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is, to not use jQuery for that but simply

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.send(formData);
```

It should do all the right things, but works only in modern browsers (don't know if you need the older ones too). For compatibility look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**.

I converted the JSON values decoded into a normal `$_POST` again.

```
$extraContent = json_decode($_POST['extra'])[0];

foreach($extraContent as $key => $extra)
   $_POST[$key] = $extra;
```